# Fractions- differences in interpretation - part of a whole

Tags: fractions

Imagine a fraction of the form $x/y$, where $y>x.$ It seems to me
that this can be interpreted in two ways. The first way is to split
one unit (say an object), into $y$ parts, and populate $x$ of those.
For instnace, splitting one apple four ways can be represented as
$1/4.$ At the same time, both $x$ and~ $y$ can represent whole
numbers/units themselves. For instance, only $1$ out of $4$ people
passed the exam, or $1/4.$ Is this a distinction without a difference?
They seem to be different applications: in the former, we have a literal
whole which we are splitting up, but in the latter, the whole is considered
as the collection of all (already whole) units. Is making a distinction
like this reasonable?

Comment: @RyanG Unfortunately, I do not think that post addresses this particular question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it *is* reasonable to distinguish between these two interpretations of $\frac14:$ divvying up $4$ apples among $4$ persons, versus slicing an apple into $4$ quarters.

But it is frequently useful to reason abstractly with fractions, such that even $\frac28$—which is differently-specified but denotes the same rational number—is treated as *equivalent* to (belonging to the same equivalence class as) the previous fraction.

Or even to treat $\frac14$ and $\frac28$ as *equal* solutions to $12x-3=0.$

P.S. This question feels like the flip-side of [numeral vs. number](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/17080/372).